# cycle while in Python searching backward and forward

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a Python dictionary, where every 100 units I have a specific value

```
from collections import defaultdict
nan = np.nan

points_dict_avg[100].append(10)
points_dict_avg[200].append(10)
points_dict_avg[300].append(10)
points_dict_avg[400].append(nan)
```

for a determinate key i need to extract the info stored in the dictionary

```
mykey = 400
```

if the value is nan i wish to select the value above or below and subtract 0.08 to the value in backward or add 0.08 in forward

```
#backward example

avg_dem_value = points_dict_avg[mykey][0]
while math.isnan(avg_dem_value):
    new_mykey = mykey - 100
    avg_dem = points_dict_avg[new_mykey][0]
    avg_dem_value = avg_dem - 0.8

#forward example
points_dict_avg = defaultdict(list)
points_dict_avg[100].append(nan)
points_dict_avg[200].append(10)
points_dict_avg[300].append(10)
points_dict_avg[400].append(10)
mykey = 100

avg_dem_value = points_dict_avg[mykey][0]
while math.isnan(avg_dem_value):
    new_mykey = mykey + 100
    avg_dem = points_dict_avg[new_mykey][0]
    avg_dem_value = avg_dem + 0.8
```

I wish to find a method in the same cycle while to look backward and forward until a value is founded, and I order to avoid `IndexError: list index out of range`

```
*#UPDATE: I find now this solution not very elegant with two while cycle. the first for backward and the second for forward. This is an example*

points_dict_avg = defaultdict(list)
points_dict_avg[100].append(nan)
points_dict_avg[200].append(nan)
points_dict_avg[300].append(nan)
points_dict_avg[400].append(40)
dem_value = 100

avg_dem_value = points_dict_avg[dem_value][0]
dem_value_back = dem_value
while math.isnan(avg_dem_value):
    dem_value_back = dem_value_back - 100
    try:
        avg_dem = points_dict_avg[dem_value_back][0]
    except:
        avg_dem_value = nan
        break
    avg_dem_value = avg_dem - 0.08
dem_value_forw = dem_value
while math.isnan(avg_dem_value):
    dem_value_forw = dem_value_forw + 100
    try:
       avg_dem = points_dict_avg[dem_value_forw][0]
    except:
        avg_dem_value = nan
        break
    avg_dem_value = avg_dem + 0.08
```

Comment: Do you have an issue, or are you just looking for more elegant code?

Comment: [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be better suited.

Comment: with try i cannot go out of the while cycle. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the issue - what do you mean 'with try i cannot go out of the while cycle'? Are you looking to go to +-200, +-300, etc.?

Comment: @AChampion, thanks. Try to repeat the last example please. It's much easy to understand and to exaplain

Comment: If you explained better what this dictionary represent... From what I understand it's a map from an integer to a list of reals (or *NaN*), where you ever only care of the first value of the list (with `[0]`) but nevertheless `append` values at the end of the list.  What is this weird structure?

Comment: You are not updating your index so it is always `dem_value - 100` so this will not terminate... did you need `100*i` where `i` is a counter around the loop.

Comment: Also don't use `try...except...` for normal cases.  If having the index going out of bound is a normal case, use a conditional `if ...`.  It makes the code cleaner and more robust since it can still send other correct exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Laerne for the tips

Comment: @Lærne not sure I agree, it's quite idiomatic to EAFP than LBYF: https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html